# Cassandra spark connector takes long delays to access table

Tags: scala, apache-spark, cassandra, spark-cassandra-connector

Our production is 5 node Cassandra cluster and trying to access cassandra table in Spark scala code through datastax connector.
Our spark jobs takes longer than usual time and found that one of cassandra node is down which causing the delay.

> Spark 2.1.0
>
> "com.datastax.spark" %% "spark-cassandra-connector" % "2.0.0-M3"
>
> scala 2.11.8

```
 SparkSession.builder().
  appName(jobName).
  config("spark.cassandra.connection.host", "27.0.5.126").
  config("spark.cassandra.connection.port", "9042").
  config("spark.cassandra.input.consistency.level", "ONE").
  config("spark.cassandra.output.consistency.level", "ONE").
  config("hive.exec.dynamic.partition", "true").
  config("hive.exec.dynamic.partition.mode", "nonstrict").
  config("hive.enforce.bucketing","true").
  enableHiveSupport().getOrCreate()

 val alerts = spark.read.format("org.apache.spark.sql.cassandra").
  options(Map("table"->tableName, "keyspace" -> keyspace)).
  load().collect()
```

When we specify all the nodes in spark config, spark connector wait for 2 minutes before timing out to create the connection pool.

```
config("spark.cassandra.connection.host", "27.0.5.126,27.0.4.223,27.0.6.85,27.0.6.59").
```

18/03/02 19:10:40 INFO NettyUtil: Found Netty's native epoll transport in the classpath, using it
18/03/02 19:10:40 INFO Cluster: New Cassandra host /27.0.5.126:9042 added
18/03/02 19:10:40 INFO Cluster: New Cassandra host /27.0.4.223:9042 added
18/03/02 19:10:40 INFO Cluster: New Cassandra host /27.0.6.85:9042 added
18/03/02 19:10:40 INFO Cluster: New Cassandra host /27.0.6.59:9042 added
18/03/02 19:10:40 INFO Cluster: New Cassandra host /27.0.6.187:9042 added
18/03/02 19:10:40 INFO CassandraConnector: Connected to Cassandra cluster: Test Cluster
18/03/02 19:12:40 WARN Session: Error creating pool to /27.0.6.187:9042
com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.ConnectionException: [/27.0.6.187] Pool was closed during initialization
at com.datastax.driver.core.HostConnectionPool$2.onSuccess(HostConnectionPool.java:149)
at com.datastax.driver.core.HostConnectionPool$2.onSuccess(HostConnectionPool.java:135)
at shade.com.datastax.spark.connector.google.common.util.concurrent.Futures$6.run(Futures.java:1319)
at

*When I pass a single cassandra host for cassandra connection (a working one), due to load balancing policy, it attempts to connect to all nodes in the datacenter1 and timed out on the bad node which took almost 2 minutes.*

18/03/02 21:17:37 INFO NettyUtil: Found Netty's native epoll transport in the classpath, using it
18/03/02 21:17:37 INFO Cluster: New Cassandra host /27.0.5.126:9042 added
18/03/02 21:17:37 INFO LocalNodeFirstLoadBalancingPolicy: Added host 27.0.5.126 (datacenter1)
18/03/02 21:17:37 INFO Cluster: New Cassandra host /27.0.4.223:9042 added
18/03/02 21:17:37 INFO LocalNodeFirstLoadBalancingPolicy: Added host 27.0.4.223 (datacenter1)
18/03/02 21:17:37 INFO Cluster: New Cassandra host /27.0.6.85:9042 added
18/03/02 21:17:37 INFO Cluster: New Cassandra host /27.0.6.59:9042 added
18/03/02 21:17:37 INFO LocalNodeFirstLoadBalancingPolicy: Added host 27.0.6.59 (datacenter1)
18/03/02 21:17:37 INFO Cluster: New Cassandra host /27.0.6.187:9042 added
18/03/02 21:17:37 INFO LocalNodeFirstLoadBalancingPolicy: Added host 27.0.6.187 (datacenter1)
18/03/02 21:17:37 INFO CassandraConnector: Connected to Cassandra cluster: Test Cluster

*how can I avoid this delay if any one of node is down in Casssandra cluster*